# LLDB and the memory addresses of library functions

Tags: macos, memory, lldb, virtual-memory

I have a "Hello World" program to which I've attached lldb. I'm trying to answer a few questions for myself about the results I get when I try to get the address of library functions:

```
(lldb) image lookup -n printf
1 match found in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib:
        Address: libsystem_c.dylib[0x000000000003f550] (libsystem_c.dylib.__TEXT.__text + 253892)
        Summary: libsystem_c.dylib`printf
(lldb) image lookup -n scanf
1 match found in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib:
        Address: libsystem_c.dylib[0x000000000003fc69] (libsystem_c.dylib.__TEXT.__text + 255709)
        Summary: libsystem_c.dylib`scanf
(lldb) expr &printf
(int (*)(const char *__restrict, ...)) $2 = 0x00007fff6f8c5550 (libsystem_c.dylib`printf)
(lldb) expr &scanf
error: unsupported expression with unknown type
```

I have three questions here:

1. What kind of address is `0x00007fff6f8c5550`? I assume it is the function pointer to printf. Is this a virtual address that exists only in the mapped space of the current process? If yes, why does another program return the same address for `printf`?
2. Assuming it's some global shared address that is the same for every process, would modifying the contents of the data at this address (which I haven't been able to do yet) create a copy of the modified memory page and will the address change? (i'm on Mac OS and I assume one process cannot change shared memory for another process)
3. Why does `expr &scanf` not work, but `expr &printf` does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. What kind of address is `0x00007fff6f8c5550`? I assume it is the function pointer to printf.

Yes, that's correct.

> Is this a virtual address that exists only
>   in the mapped space of the current process?

Well, yes and no. It is a virtual address specific to your process and you should not assume it's valid in another process. But:

> If yes, why does another
>   program return the same address for `printf`?

As an optimization, macOS uses a shared mapping for a lot of the system libraries. They are loaded once at boot and used by all processes. For a given boot, the address is constant across all such processes. However, the address is randomized each boot for security.

> 2. Assuming it's some global shared address that is the same for every process, would modifying the contents of the data at this address
>      (which I haven't been able to do yet) create a copy of the modified
>      memory page and will the address change?

Well, it is mapped copy-on-write. So, modifying it would create a copy. However, that wouldn't change its address. The OS would simply modify the mapping so that the memory around that address is private to your process.

> (i'm on Mac OS and I assume
>   one process cannot change shared memory for another process)

Well, processes can cooperate to have writable shared memory. But, in general, you're correct that security precautions prevent unwanted modifications to a process's memory.

> 3. Why does `expr &scanf` not work, but `expr &printf` does?

Your program (presumably) doesn't use `scanf`, so there's no debugging information regarding it. The main thing `lldb` is missing is the type of `scanf`. If you use a cast expression, it can work:

```
(lldb) p scanf
error: 'scanf' has unknown type; cast it to its declared type to use it
(lldb) p &scanf
error: unsupported expression with unknown type
(lldb) p (int(*)(const char * __restrict, ...))scanf
(int (*)(const char *__restrict, ...)) $3 = 0x00007fffd7e958d4 (libsystem_c.dylib`scanf)
```

Conversely, it works for `printf` because your program does use it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write all this. Helps me (and hopefully others, too) a lot!

Comment: One clarification.  Ken is right about why printf is in a constant location.   But macOS has another defensive tactic - ASLR - which randomized the load location of all the libraries that are not in the shared cache of libraries.  Unless you tell it otherwise, lldb requests that the OS disable ASLR when it runs programs.  macOS still honors this request (iOS does not.) So when you run programs under the debugger on macOS, if nothing else has changed, all the libraries will load at the same locations run to run.

Comment: Another minor clarification, printf works but scanf doesn't because printf is used SO commonly in expressions that lldb forces a declaration of it into all the expressions it runs.  In general, the compiler only emits debug information for functions where they are defined.  The fact that you use a function doesn't cause clang to emit debug information into the using binary.

Comment: However, since the C library headers are built into clang modules these days, `expr -l objc -- @import Darwin` will import all the standard C library declarations into lldb's expression parser.